# change Text to speech - TTS to ringer volume

Tags: android, text-to-speech, volume

How can I control TTS Volume?
I do not want to use AudioManager because audiomanager cannot set by press of the volume button on a Galaxy Tab (That I think it's a ringer volume).
So, how can I change TTS speaker to ringer volume?

OR how can I set output of text to speech to STREAM_RING?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution.
I try to make TTS ouput as ring volume. but it didn't work.
so the solution is change the volume controller of galaxy tab to control media volume instead.
with this code

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

put this in onCreate() and thing goes fine.
Hope this help for someone who face the same problem.

Credit: Thank you so much P'Tee